# How to solve an error on GAE for "Unexpected attribute 'dispatch' for object of type AppInfoExternal."

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Please tell me to deploy my project for GAE.

I can not deploy my project because of the following error.

```
%appcfg.py update app.yaml dispatch.yaml worker.yaml
(omissions)
appcfg.py: error: Error parsing ./dispatch.yaml: Unexpected attribute 'dispatch' for object of type AppInfoExternal.
in "./dispatch.yaml", line 4, column 1.
```

This project has the following yaml files in direct project folder.

app.yaml

dipatch.yaml

worker.yaml

The following is dispatch.yaml.

```
application: my-app

dispatch:
- url: "*/worker/*"
  module: worker
```

The following is worker.yaml.

```
application: my-app
module: worker
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
version: uno
runtime: python27
instance_class: B1
manual_scaling:
    instances: 1
handlers:
- url: /_ah/start
    script: my-worker.app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, make sure you run `appcfg.py update_dispatch`, which is a separate command from `update`

Answer (score 1):

Wrong indenting.  Should be:

```
application: my-app

dispatch:
  - url: "*/worker/*"
    module: worker
```

Comment: I think you are **strict**, but no spaces indentation in this case doesn't seems to be required. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17014973/338986, also [google doesn't seem to be bothered](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_About_app_yaml).

Comment: well, in the `dispatch.yaml` docs, Google uses indentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#dispatch_file  The error you received refers to `line 4, column 1`, which is the line that should be indented.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `dispatch.yaml` doesn't seem to be allowed to be an argument of `appcfg.py update`. The error message must indicate that.

Try:

```
appcfg.py update app.yaml worker.yaml
```

Also, `dispatch.yaml` are not an [application config](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig), but [the dispatch file](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing). So you may not allowed to write attributes other than `dispatch`.

Answer (score 1):

modules included in dispatch must come before the dispatch.yaml in appcfg.py update, so correct command is:

```
appcfg.py update app.yaml worker.yaml dispatch.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into an identical error message and eventually what I discovered is that Google requires the dispatch file to be called `dispatch.yaml`.

My file was something like `web.dispatch.yaml`, which Google does not like. Renaming my file to `dispatch.yaml` did the trick.

Comment: Did you find any solution to add some context here? (e.g. `dispatch.prod.yaml`)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem in latest gcp deployment, i.e, using `gcloud` command.

I got rid of `application` from `dispatch.yaml` and this error was gone.