# Keep indentation for array value in parsed YAML frontmatter

Tags: ruby, yaml-front-matter

I am using https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/front_matter_parser to parse and update values in the frontmatter of my markdown files.

The following code removes the original indentation of two spaces for array values:

```
require 'front_matter_parser'

class FrontMatterUpdater
  def self.run(path)
    parsed = FrontMatterParser::Parser.parse_file(path)
    front_matter = parsed.front_matter
    
    front_matter['redirect_from'] = Array(front_matter['redirect_from'])
    front_matter['redirect_from'] << 'new_entry2'
    front_matter['redirect_from'].uniq!
    
    new_content = [YAML.dump(front_matter), '---', "\n\n", parsed.content].join
    
    File.write(path, new_content)
  end
end

FrontMatterUpdater.run('test.md')
```

**Content of my test.md file (same path):**.

```
---
redirect_from:
  - new_entry0
  - new_entry1
---
```

**Script result (indentation has been removed by the parser):**

```
---
redirect_from:
- new_entry0
- new_entry1
- new_entry2
---
```

[YAML indentation for array in hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014460/yaml-indentation-for-array-in-hash) confirms that both versions (indented and not) is valid YAML syntax.

But I'd love to keep the indentation for readability.

Do you see any option to keep the indentation of 2 spaces for the array values?

Comment: I cannot find any configuration that would provide this output. Indentation levels are controlled by the `Emitter` and the visiting of an `Array` creates a sequence which will have the same indentation level as the key.

Comment: I understand. I'd need to implement my own way of reading the YAML file and parsing the front matter. Too complex for the use case, I will the output without indentation. Thanks for your comment. Learned a lot about YAML today :)

Comment: Just to let you know. I found at least a potential workaround. I could run yq in a post processing step, e.g. `find _docs  -exec yq e -I2 --front-matter="process" -i '.yq_formatted = true' {} \;`, you can check the details in  https://www.baeldung.com/linux/yq-utility-processing-yaml or https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq

Comment: Works even better by using a deletion of a non-existing YAML key: `find _docs  -exec yq e -I2 --front-matter="process" -i 'del(.street_address.xyz)' {} \;`